# WSMModelData Error

Tags: warning-messages, system-modeler

I am getting this error message when I run simulation in Mathematica that makes iterations to a SystemModeler model.

```
WSMModelData: The models parameter values were not translated completely. Untranslated parts are wrapped in Missing[..]
```

Although it doesn't seem to affect the results somehow !! Can anybody explain the reason behind this error ?

Answer (score 2):

There was some part of the model that could not be fully translated from Modelica to Mathematica.

If you aren't seeing any further problems, it probably means the parts that couldn't be translated were in parameters you are not using for anything.